# Is heat bending of pvc conduit allowed?

Tags: electrical

I am interested if bending of the pvc conduit is allowed using heat to 90 degrees in larger radius. Also, is there max number of 90 degree turns allowed in a circuit?

Comment: The gray Sch 40 PVC that is commonly used for non metallic conduit, has available large radius "sweeps" that come in 90 and 45 degree. Maybe that will do you. If not, electrical companies that I have worked with use a heating blanket specified for the task of heating PVC conduit to bend custom sections of pipe. I have bent pipe over a wood fire, and other times over a heating element, rotating the pipe to it heat evenly to use on non critical needs. To my knowledge no more bends that make a 360 degree turn, in other words, 4-90 degree bends in a single run. There is a rule for it somewhere.

Comment: So if I have a 120' run but I have to make more than total of 360 degrees, what do I do? I have to go up the wall in garage, then turn twice at 90, then under the patio, than down to soil, again one more 90 and then 2 45, and then up to post another 90.

Comment: You can put an accessible junction box in a wall to satisfy the need for code compliance. That is if you don't mind a blank plate on the wall or ceiling covering it. It is there for a reason, as Ecnerwal states so well, embrace it. It will be extremely contrary to pull a cable a great distance through that many elbows. As a suggestion, DO put a J box either in the interior garage wall run regular cable there, then at the J box at the garage wall use UF wire to go outside with. This may get you past the issue. It's all in the planning.

Comment: You could also use the LB fitting as Ecnerwal suggests at the outside wall of the garage to serve as an elbow and pull station, but it will not serve as a J box to wire nut together a change in the wire.

Comment: @Jack: Are there any disadvantages in using UF wire (from what I read it cannot be in condui) vs THWN in conduit, other than having to dig 24" for UF wire?

Comment: IMHO, THWN in conduit is in every way superior to (and often cheaper than) UF or any other direct burial wire. More rodent resistant, more damage resistant from future digging (do mark it well with "buried electric line below" tape in the top six inches of the trench) and you can pull out the wire and replace it without having to dig a new trench.

Comment: Ecnerwal has covered that very well about the THWN. The only advantage with the UF, you could eliminate the conduit. To answer the question about UF in conduit, I believe there is no problem with it, except for the expense. The reason why I mentioned UF here, because that is what has been used once outside with a conduit after it gets below grade. I did not detail that in my earlier post. My apologies.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need a junction box or other access every 360 degrees (or rather, **no more than** 360 degrees between junction boxes or access points.) It's to make it possible to actually pull the wire into the conduit, so embrace it.

Things like an LB count as an access point and are frequently used to make this practical, but where needed, simply inserting a junction box in the run is easy to do - no need to cut wires or make a junction in it, you just need the access.

As for bending, yes, large radius sweeps can be purchased pre-made (real electrical supply .vs. home cheapo, etc.) and yes, you can use heat to bend PVC conduit - I've done it with boiling water, or you can rent the heat blanket type benders. I would not suggest direct flame for bending heat. You do need to take care not to kink the conduit when bending it.